# Cannot set underline for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uilabel

I have a UILabel which have text: "Something here and privacy policy", I just want to create underline for the text **privacy policy** but the code not affect. If I create underline for full text of my label then it worked, but it's not what I want.Here is my code:

```
     NSString *str = self.myLabel.text;
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
        NSRange index = [str rangeOfString:@"privacy policy"];
        if (index.location != NSNotFound){
            [attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(index.location, index.length)];
          //if I change index.location by 0 then it worked, 
          //with the underline start at the begin text of mylabel but that not what I expected
            [self.myLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
         }
```

Is have something wrong with my code(my app support for iOS 7 and latter)?

Comment: There is a known bug in iOS 8 that prevents the underline from appearing in a `UILabel` unless you start from the 1st character. Create a simple test case and submit a bug to Apple. The more people that complain, the better chance Apple will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your info, but I don't know how to submit bugs to Apple.

Comment: https://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: I cannot access this website, always timeout.

Comment: It's https, not http.

Comment: Could you use a custom font which is underlined? Not an ideal answer but it could work if all else fails

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily fix your issue, you can split your String into 2 NSMutableAttributedString with latter string having text "privacy policy". You can then underline the whole text and concatenate the two strings.

```
NSString *str = self.myLabel.text;
    NSRange index = [str rangeOfString:@"privacy policy"];
    if (index.location != NSNotFound){
        NSString *tempString = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, index.location - 1)];
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tempString];

        NSString *privacyString=[str substringFromIndex:index.location];
        NSAttributedString *attributedString1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:privacyString];
        [attributedString1 addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString1.length)];
      //with the underline start at the begin text of mylabel but that not what I expected
        NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
        [mutableAttString appendAttributedString: attributedString];
        [mutableAttString appendAttributedString:attributedString1];
        [self.myLabel setAttributedText:mutableAttString];
     }
```

Comment: not really understand the way to do with your suggestion?

Comment: How does this fix the issue? The bug is with `UILabel`. It won't show any underline unless the first character is underlined.

Comment: Then you need to take 2 UILabel with 2nd UILabel containing the text "Privacy Policy".

Comment: @ArunGupta: 2 UILabel is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this piece of code.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 250, 40)];
label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

NSString *text = @"Something and Privacy Policy";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc ]initWithString:text];

NSInteger location = [@"Something and " length]-1;
NSInteger length = [@"Privacy Policy" length];
[attrString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:NSMakeRange(location, length)];
label.attributedText=attrString;

[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Did you try this code? Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes Maddy. I just wrote a quick code segment :)

Comment: also tried with your code, but it doesn't worked. As @rmaddy said, it's a bug on iOS 8. my code can work on iOS 7 but doesn't work on iOS8.

Comment: Hi Lee. I tested this on iOS 7. It should work for iOS 6 as well. Apparently, I don't have an iOS 8 device to test this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to underline a portion of a text is to use Interface Builder (Designer first, coder second). Granted this might not be what you want but for a temporary solution I propose the following:

**Instructions** 
1) Place a UILabel in your viewController of choice and add constraints as needed.
2) Click on your label, replace the text and go to *Attributes Inspector*. (Image 1) 
3) Change your UILabel from 'Plain Text' to 'Attributed' 
4) Highlight the portion you want underlined as shown in Image 2 below and press the 'T' in a square. 
5) On the toolbar of the window that shows up, you'll see an underlined 'T'. Select 'single' (Image 3).

**Images**

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]